# ActiveMQ Handling Messages thru REST

Tags: java, rest, activemq-classic

I am new to ActiveMQ, we had a ActiveMQ Server else where location, we are unable to connect thru tcp socket, But able to cousume the message using REST command

```
http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://orders.input
```

I have 99K+ messages in ActiveMQ, need consume using REST command and need to store in a text file,

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.dnb.e2e.automation.util.CommonUtil;
import com.dnb.e2e.automation.util.WebServiceUtil;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.config.SSLConfig;
import com.jayway.restassured.config.SessionConfig;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Headers;
public class MQwithRest {
     public static String getResponse() throws Exception 
     {
        String url = "http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://SAMPLEQUEUE";

        String response = "a";

            while(response!=""){
            try {
                response =  given().header("content-type", "application/json")
                        .request()
                        .config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames()))
                        .when().get(url).asString();
                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            return "empty";
        }

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
     {
                 System.out.println(MQwithRest.getResponse());
     }
}
```

In the above code i am displaying consumed messages at output side. When I am implementing thru rest i am able to consume only one message at a time per session.

Can any body help for Consuming 99k+ message with in a single session using REST service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also tunnel [JMS client over HTTP](http://activemq.apache.org/http-and-https-transports-reference.html). 
That way, you can get bypass any non-HTTP restrictions in your network and still use the JMS terminology.

Using the rest web app bundled you are a bit limited to the semantics of retrieving messages. Anyway, you should be able to get all messages using plain HTTP/Rest anyway. Simply use a loop to get messages.

Comment: Thanks @Petter Nordander